# Is it possible insert AspectRatio in Column?

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like insert a AspectRatio in column. And insert this column in a ListView.
Is it possible?
I want create a percentage with under information about it.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
        left: 28,
        right: 28,
        bottom: 8,
        top: 8,
      ),
      child: Container(
        height: heightElement,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(16)),
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: SVConst.circularItemsColors[index].withOpacity(0.5),
              spreadRadius: 5,
              blurRadius: 7,
              offset: Offset(0, 3), // changes position of shadow
            ),
          ],
        ),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              height: 0.7 * heightElement,
              child: Expanded(
                child: AspectRatio(
                  aspectRatio: 1.3,
                  child: Center(
                    child: CircularPercentIndicator(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                      radius: 120.0,
                      lineWidth: 13.0,
                      percent: (double.parse(percentuage) / 100),
                      center: Text(
                        percentuage + "%",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20.0),
                      ),
                      footer: Container(
                        child: AutoSizeText(
                          nameItem,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: SVConst.circularItemsColors[index],
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 17.0),
                        ),
                      ),
                      circularStrokeCap: CircularStrokeCap.round,
                      progressColor: SVConst.circularItemsColors[index],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

but it throw exception.
I try insert a AspectRatio in a Container with 70% f height respect it parent but it not works.

You have suggest for me?
Can you help me please?

Comment: remove your expanded widget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Expanded` widget is supposed to have as parents either a `Row`, `Column`, or a `Flex`. Hence the exception.

Remove the `Expanded` widget from `AspectRatio`.

Answer (score 0):

```
   height: 0.7 * heightElement,
```

this this wrong , you need to remove the appbar and status bar height then u can able to get the exact 0.7 percent .

Now You can use 0.6 as we can consider the appbar and statusbar size may consume 0.1 .

So Your code should be,

```
   height: 0.6 * heightElement,
```